# HtmlDecode dont work using Razor MVC inside html attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-entities

I´m trying to write the word **Márcia** in html using MVC4 / Razor on view but the result is wrong like:

```
<span title="M&#225;rcia">Márcia</span>
```

Note: the word inside the tag *SPAN* print output correctly, but the word in **same property** of model (@Model.Name) display with the character encoded `&#225;`

Already try all commands bellow, but anyone work when apply inside html attribute:

```
@Html.Raw(model.Name)

@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.Name))

@Html.Raw(Server.HtmlDecode(model.Name))

@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(model.Name)

@Server.HtmlDecode(model.Name)
```

Why the html decode don't work when used inside a html attribute? How to make it work?

Comment: Whats is the value of model.Name. <span title="@Html.Raw("M&#225;rcia")">@Html.Raw("M&#225;rcia")</span> worked for me

Comment: Also provide some view code

Comment: Try using `@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name).ToString())` and let me know the result.

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me.  Here is my `HomeController` code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new HomeModel();
        model.Name1 = "Márcia";
        model.Name2 = "M&#225;rcia";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here is my Home Index view:

```
@model mvctestappweb.Models.HomeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@Model.Name1
<br />
@Html.Raw(Model.Name2)
```

The output on the view looks like this:

```
Márcia
Márcia
```

---

**EDIT**:  I see.  The issue is that as soon as you put the RAW into the HTML `<span>` tag that it converts the á to `&#225;` no matter what.  I played with this a good bit and was unable to find a way to stop this from happening.  So, here are two work arounds that might work for you:

(I know this isnt ideal, but it was the best work around I could find.)

My controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new HomeModel();
        model.Name = "Márcia";
        model.SpanHtml = "<span title='Márcia'>Márcia</span>";
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Here my view:

```
@model mvctestappweb.Models.HomeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

1: @Html.Raw("<span title=\"" + @Html.Raw(Model.Name) + "\">" + @Model.Name + "</span>")
<br />
2: @Html.Raw(@Model.SpanHtml)
```

The output on the view looks like this:

```
1: Márcia
2: Márcia
```

My HTML source looks like this:

```
1: <span title="Márcia">Márcia</span>
<br />
2: <span title='Márcia'>Márcia</span>
```

Comment: Hello, its work for me too, because the second property its outside of html tag. Please try put the Model.Name2 into html attribute like <span title = "@Model.Name2" /> . The error persist

Comment: @jmrnet I have a Viewbag with document list and one of the document have the name "test1>test2". My html looks like   @Html.DropDownList("Documents", (SelectList)ViewBag.Documents, "--Select Document--")
When it runs in the dropdown list "test1>test2" shown as test2&gt;test1. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You can put attribute name together with value.

```
@{  
    var title = "title='Márcia'";  
}  

<span @Html.Raw(title)>Márcia</span>
```